# ng-repeat with nested nested objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object which has comments and have replies obj that replies obj further have nested replies obj. How I can render it on ng-repeat. I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404341/nested-comments-in-angularjs-with-ng-repeat), it makes my replies object undefined. 
e.g this

```
<div  ng-repeat="it in item.CommentReplies=it.CommentReplies  track by $index" >
```

why it making my object undefined is it right solution ?
here is my object
[image]

Comment: is item an array?

Comment: ys array of objects @digit

Comment: please post your fakedata as example a.e. `item`

Comment: picture shown is item (obj of array) @MaximShoustin has nested obj

Comment: @Asad I think you have enough reputation to put object as code instead post image. It will help us a lot to track down the issue

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30367932/6712896) might answer you

Answer (score 1):

You should use two ng-repeat like this :

```
<div class="replylist" ng-repeat="it in item.CommentReplies track by $index">
{{it.Text}}
      <div ng-repeat="comment in it.CommentReplies">
      {{comment.Text}}
      </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.
Would have left a comment but don't have enough reputation.

Comment: what if there is nested json in it.CommentReplies ?

Comment: If I understood correctly what you say, you can have an unlimited number of nested array of CommentReplies in each CommentReplies item ?

Comment: If that's what you're trying to do, I don't think it's possible with ng-repeat, but you can write a recursive function which builds the html structure and then call it inside your html code, like this :     $scope.displayComment = function (item) {
$scope.htmlResult += item.Text + '<br/>';
for(var i = 0; i < item.CommentReplies.length: i++)
 {
  $scope.displayComment(item.CommentReplies[i]);
 }
}     <div class="replylist" ng-init="displayComment(item)">
 {{htmlResult}}
</div>    I did not test my code, but if you can give us a sample of your data I could test it.

Comment: hi do you check the solution link in my question that i want to try @hmk

Comment: Based on your link apparently it's possible with ng-repeat, he uses 2 ng-repeat to create a recursive call.In your case you would put this somewhere to call the structure the first time :
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-include="'comment.html'" > 
And you create a view comment.html,and put the second ng-repeat in it,with ng-include to let it call itself:
<div ng-repeat="item in comments = item.CommentReplies" ng-include="'comment.html'" ng-init="level = level + 1">
"comments" is used just another name for item.CommentReplies,I don't think you need it,he uses it bcs he applies an orderby